# x86 / x64 issue with Enterprise Library 5 Oracle connection string in .NET 4.0 ASP.NET web application project

Tags: .net, oracle, x86, 64-bit, connection-string

My goal is to be able to read from an Oracle database, using a connection string in my web.config file for an ASP.NET application which is running on Windows Server 2008 in IIS 7.  Note, that I'm making the connection using Enterprise Library 5 syntax.  From the forums I've read, it's telling me I need the x64 version of the Oracle client.  Because I have legacy DLL files, I want to run as x86 for now.  Is this even possible?  It's going to introduce more complexity if I introduce x64 with my x86 DLL files, but if that's my only option, let me know how this can be done if there's no way to run Oracle client as x86.

My application is throwing an Exception on this line:

```
using (IDataReader dataReader = db.ExecuteReader(command))
```

Exception:

***Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException.  This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed.***

When I right click the project in Visual Studio 2010, it shows me that my Platform is set to "Active (Any CPU)".  And the Platform target is set to "x86".

In IIS 7 (on Windows Server 2008), I have the Enable 32-Bit Applications attribute (under Advanced Settings of my web site application pool) set to "True".

Windows environment variable "Path" has "D:\oracle\product\11.1.0\client_1\bin;" set for the Oracle path.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common;
using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation;
using System.Data.Common;
using Web.Controls.Shared;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
```

...

```
    static List<DWObject> GetOracleTables(string databaseGroup)
    {
        Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(databaseGroup);
        StringBuilder getQuery = new StringBuilder
            (@"select table_name from all_tables");

        List<DWObject> objectList = new List<DWObject>();

        DbCommand command = db.GetSqlStringCommand(getQuery.ToString());

        // Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException.  This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed.
        // It can't find a 64-bit version of the Oracle client libraries.  This has nothing to do with the .NET framework, please contact Oracle for support.
        using (IDataReader dataReader = db.ExecuteReader(command))
        {
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                if (dataReader["table_name"] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    DWObject dwo = new DWObject();
                    dwo.dwobject_name = dataReader["table_name"].ToString();
                    objectList.Add(dwo);
                }
            }
        }

        return objectList;
    }
```

Connection string via service account:

```
  <add name="TestDatabase" connectionString="server=xxx;Data Source=xxx;User ID=xxx;password=xxx;" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient"  />
```

---

**Edit 7/17/2015:**

Funny that I found my own post here.  Now I got a different error.  But I'm trying the same solution.

```
db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle
>   client software version 8.1.7 or greater.

Comment: attempting to download the 32 bit Oracle client.. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win32soft-098987.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just downloaded the 32 bit Oracle client.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win32soft-098987.html

---

Now today I discovered why I was getting this error.

> Additional information: System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle
>   client software version 8.1.7 or greater.

The `version 8.1.7` error above had nothing to do with any setup what so ever!  I had another issue on my PC where Windows could not access %windir%, which meant Windows could not access any of the environment variables because they are accessible via the %windir% (C:\Windows\System32) folder.  Another weird behavior in Windows during this time was that any programs or icons found in this %windir% folder were causing those programs to show a dummy icon (e.g. Accessories > Paint, Windows Explorer, Command Prompt, Remote Desktop Connection, etc...).  Today, I right clicked one of those programs in the start menu that it didn't have an icon for, and chose "Run as Administrator", and now the icons show!  Now Visual Studio is not throwing this error.  I get a completely new error in my Console Application.  This new error is due to the Project properties > Build > Platform Target > Any CPU value.  I changed from Any CPU to x86 to resolve the error.

```
DataTable dt = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand).Tables[0];
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw
>   BadImageFormatException.  This problem will occur when running in 64
>   bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed.

Comment: C:\app\macgyver\product\11.2.0\client_1